# Расширение сертификата типа UTF8String

Tags: c, x509certificate, cryptoapi

В связи с приказом ФСБ N795 от 27 декабря 2011 г. (пункт 29) в сертификат требуется добавить расширение subjectSignTool (OID: 1.2.643.100.111) типа UTF8String SIZE(1..200). Добавляю расширение через метод addExtentionToRequest, предварительно кодируя данные в ASN.1 и BASE64 подобным способом:

```
char extensionValue[] = "test";

CRYPT_OBJID_BLOB myBlob = {
    (DWORD)strlen(extensionValue),
    (BYTE*)extensionValue
};

DWORD cbEncoded;
BYTE *pbEncoded;

bool checkASN1Encoding = CryptEncodeObjectEx(X509_ASN_ENCODING | PKCS_7_ASN_ENCODING, X509_OCTET_STRING, &myBlob, 0, NULL, pbEncoded, &cbEncoded);

wchar_t pszString[100];
DWORD dwLength = 100;
bool checkEncodingToBase64Test = CryptBinaryToStringW(pbEncoded, cbEncoded, CRYPT_STRING_BASE64, (LPWSTR)pszString, &dwLength);


BSTR bstrValue = pszString;
BSTR bstrName = SysAllocString(L"1.2.643.100.111");

HRESULT checkAddingExtention = pEnroll->addExtensionToRequest(0, bstrName, bstrValue);
```

Расширение добавляется в запрос на сертификат, но имеет вид Octet String:

```
Requested Extensions:
    X509v3 Extended Key Usage: 
        TLS Web Client Authentication, E-mail Protection, 1.2.643.2.2.34.6
    X509v3 Key Usage: 
        Digital Signature, Non Repudiation, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
    1.2.643.100.111: 
        test

SEQUENCE {:
   OBJECT IDENTIFIER '1 2 643 100 111'
   OCTET STRING 74 65 73 74 56 61 6C 75 65
}
```

А должно быть что-то на подобие:

```
SEQUENCE {
   OBJECT IDENTIFIER '1 2 643 100 111'
   OCTET STRING, encapsulates {
      UTF8String
      'test'
   }
}
```

Пробовал использовать CryptEncodeObjectEx с 2ым параметром X509_ANY_STRING и X509_UNICODE_ANY_STRING, но безуспешно. Как же все-таки правильно реализовать добавление такого расширения?

Comment: Ответ найден вот тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40844688/add-extension-to-certificate-using-cryptoapi
и вот тут: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41064225/encode-utf8string-to-asn1-with-cryptoapi